# Plural for indeclinable nouns

Tags: склонение, существительные, множественное-число

Some foreign nouns are indeclinable (take [пальто](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE#Russian) for example), yet sometimes we want to express many of it. How to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just leave it as is. Like 'deer' in English - "One deer", "many deer", etc.

> У неё уже есть три пальто - зачем ей ещё одно?
>
> Он может делать два сальто подряд.
>
> На столе лежат два портмоне.